# Calling typeface.js on HTML fetched by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, types, typeface.js

I have a page where I'm fetching a Wordpress main index to handle my 'news feed', imported via jQuery.ajax.  I'm also using typeface.js on the same page to have better typeface control.  I want to call typeface.js on the elements in the Ajax'd HTML.  The problem is that I'm not sure how to do that, since the structure of it is unfamiliar to me.  It doesn't have functions to call in the normal sense, otherwise I'd just use those on success with the ajax request.

Does anyone have experience with typeface.js to help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you append the returned contents to your document you can call:
_typeface_js.renderDocument()
which will render the new content

Answer (score 0):

You could include typeface.js only after you've Ajax'd your contents, so it applies to that content as well.

To include files dynamically you could try this [jQuery plugin](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/index.php/jquery/17-includemany-jquery-include-many.html).